# Upload max size in PHP?

Tags: php, ini, uploading

Is it possible for the upload of ~100 MB files using PHP?

If so, what changes need to occur in the configuration file (`php.ini`)?

Sri

Comment: "possible" !== "good idea"

Comment: @symbcbean I'd say that really depends, doesn't it? If you have a public-facing upload interface of some sort and you can't use FTP...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing upload\_max\_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

Answer (score 30):

The following options are relevant:

- PHP: [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) (in php.ini or .htaccess only, won't work using `ini_set()`)
- PHP: [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) (ditto)
- PHP: [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) (ditto, thanks @Thorstein, forgot this one)

and possibly

- Apache: [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Answer (score 2):

In your `php.ini` adjust the value of:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M //needs to be in {x}M format
```

And allow larger post size:

```
post_max_size = 100M
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow for larger uploads with PHP you must change a few settings in the php.ini file (upload_max_filesize, max_input_time, memory_limit, max_execution_time, post_max_size). You can find your php.ini file under you PHP installation directory, and more information about the required settings [here](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `max_input_time`, +1. But `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` don't really apply - not if the uploaded file is merely moved to another location.

Answer (score 1):

This dumfounded me for a while so just wanted to add:

If your project *also* use **nginx** (e.g. a buildpack), you may have to add `client_max_body_size 100M;` to your `nginx.conf` file since nginx defaults to only `1M` (1 MB) - in addition to the PHP settings mentioned above.

Regarding PHP settings, I create a `.user.ini` file at root level of my projects to change the few settings I want to override from the default `php.ini` file.

In my setup (using [dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/)) it was located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, then added the extra line via `nano nginx.conf`. I don't *directly* use nginx, but my buildpack adds it.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the timeout of the server and the max file size in the php.ini file.

http://blog.jc21.com/2007-05-03/change-the-maximum-upload-size-with-php/

EDIT: You may not need to change the timeout of the server as that really would depend on which server you are running things on.

Comment: Upload time does not count toward the execution time.

Comment: @Pekka yeah I was just thinking about that after I wrote it and that is why I added the edit.