# PHP video file upload problem

Tags: php, file, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload max size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php)

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
```

i make these 2 settings in php.ini and upload video less than 400MB 
but can't upload

Comment: If you "can't upload", maybe your ethernet cable has come loose?  Or more seriously, you should describe what you tried, what error behaviour you got, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: What's the setting in `max_input_time`?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand your question, but those variables aren't the only ones needed for a successful file uploading.

1. Check if your HTML `<form>` has the
   proper [`enctype`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) set.
2. You have to add `<input type="hidden"
   name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000"
   />` to your `<form>` too. This input field specifies the maximum uploadable file size in bytes.