# Increasing the maximum post size

Tags: php, apache

There is a lot of data being submitted no file uploads and the `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` is being exceeded. Can this be increased?

Comment: I assume that you are using apache, which is actually limiting the post size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload max size in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php)

Comment: Read [this article on drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/97193) on how the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize relate

Answer (score 144):

There are 2 different places you can set it:

php.ini

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

.htaccess / httpd.conf / virtualhost include

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Which one to use depends on what you have access to.

.htaccess will not require a server restart, but php.ini and the other apache conf files will.

Comment: where to access .htaccess file. I am using ubuntu

Comment: Do you need to restart for these to take affect?

Comment: You need to restart your webserver when changing PHP.ini

Answer (score 79):

I had a situation when variables went missing from POST and all of the above answers didn't help. It turned out that

```
max_input_vars=1000
```

was set by default and POST in question had more than that.
This may be a problem.

Comment: Great thank you - this was the only thing that did the trick, for me.

Comment: it's the right answer. be aware that you should not set this value from php but it must be set from php.ini or htaccess. for htaccess use like this: php_value max_input_vars 4000

Comment: Thanks this max_input_vars=3000, works for me, not post_max_size

Answer (score 25):

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 8):

We can Increasing the maximum limit using `.htaccess` file.

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
php_value max_input_time         10800
php_value max_execution_time     10800
php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          120M
```

If sometimes other way are not working, this way is working perfect.

Answer (score 6):

You can increase that in php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Answer (score 6):

I had been facing similar problem in downloading big files this works fine for me now:

```
safe_mode = off
max_input_time = 9000
memory_limit = 1073741824
post_max_size = 1073741824
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1073741824
max_file_uploads = 100
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify both max post size and max file size limit in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
LimitRequestBody 1024000000
```

Answer (score 1):

php.ini
Change setting max_input_vars from default 1000 to 10000 for enought json post data.
It worked for me.

```
max_input_vars=10000
```

Answer (score -1):

Only add the below 3 lines in `.htaccess` file, which is **in your root folder of the project.**

```
php_value memory_limit 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
```

It will completely assist you in resolving your problem.