# Sending AJAX request fails with large amount of data

Tags: ajax

I am using AJAX to send requests to doPost method.

When I add large amount of data to the request, I cannot get the request in the Servlet class.
The page just hangs without causing an error.

If I send less data with AJAX request,its working fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the default content length is 8192, u have to define it expicitly increase it

Comment: post some code, post the AJAX call, what headers are u defining.. post some booty man!

Answer (score 1):

There could be a lot of reason for this to happen. I suggest you (if you can) to look at the server side application you are pointing with your ajax post request. That application could not manage such a large request you are trying to do and simply drop it silently. 
Moreover the great part of web servers, allow the administrator to configure the  maximum size of requests, so that if your request exceed such amount it will be dropped.
If you don't find your way, you may also find useful to see what really happens 'under the hood' using tools like Firebug http://getfirebug.com for Firefox, or Opera DragonFly, or Safari Web Development Tools, ecc.. 
In some extreme cases using sniffer like tcpdump or Wireshark could help you improve your knoledge of what is really happening.

Comment: Thanks Giovanni.Is there any way to extend the size of the requests?

Comment: Yes sure! Take a look a this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: @vijay please rate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be resolved by changing the Request Limit in Apache configuration (if you use Apache):

```
LimitXMLRequestBody 0
```

In the example above, 0 means unlimited. But you can set a larger-than-default number that works for you.

More info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitxmlrequestbody