# How to reject heavy incoming http posts

Tags: apache, http

Is it possible to reject http POST requests which are unusually heavy.

For example if there is only one textbox in a html form of size 200 characters, but I simulate a http post request through tools like wget and send a huge amount of text against that parameter is it possible at the proxy server,say Apache, to reject such requests

Comment: What about php.ini directive post_max_size ?

Comment: @jtheman thanks I will google around, is there a link that you found useful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size is a place to start. This post is really about increasing the limit but for you it's just the same I guess...

Comment: @jtheman thanks that seems helpful, I will try it out...