# Laravel 3 - POST Content-Length Exception

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-3

Running Laravel 3.

I am trying to upload files with the laravel framework. If the file is larger than the php setting for `upload_max_filesize` it throws the exception below.

I have tried this in my controller and routes with no success (the `if` statement runs - it sets a session - but the exception is still thrown showing the error page)

```
if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 8380000) {
    //do stuff here because its too big
    // set a session and exit()
}
```

**How can I prevent this exception from being thrown without upping the php memory limits?**

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

POST Content-Length of 9306598 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes
Location:

Unknown on line 0
```

As a side note, this question has been asked atleast twice in the laravel forum with no good answer given except for 'increase your php memory limits'.

**EDIT**: the problem seems to be that laravel is loading all the `_POST` inputs before I can even check them in the route or controllers. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like PHP's [max post size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size),  which defaults to 8M on many systems (around 8388608 bytes).  There is nothing you can do in Laravel to get around this as it is handled/managed/configured at the PHP level.  Read [Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135485/1269513) to see how to change this.

Comment: Yes, I know it is php max_post_size. So there is no way around this except for upping the limits?

Comment: The only other solutions I have seen on the web are flash based plugins that chunk the upload and then join the chunks together again on the server.  Have a look at http://www.plupload.com/ if that's the way you want to go

Answer (score 0):

PHP is raising this **Warning** and Laravel is threating it as a fatal error.
This is done in `Error::shutdown`, any PHP error thrown will result in an application shutdown due this error.

A solution I've found is to filter which error types are allowed to end in `Error::shutdown`.
The downside is:

- Needs to modify a laravel file: `laravel/laravel.php` which is not a good idea if you plan to update laravel with new versions (something that will hardly happen now that version 4.1 out there).
- Could not fully test if this implies some side effect in laravel behaviour by not aborting Warning errors.

This is the modification I made in file `laravel/laravel.php` line 46:

```
register_shutdown_function(function()
{
    require_once path('sys').'error'.EXT;
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ( $error!==null )
    {
        if( $error['type']!=E_WARNING )
        {
            Error::shutdown();
        }
     }
});
```