# How to hide warning post_max_size exceeded?

Tags: php

In production I don't want to show the following error:

```html
<b>Warning</b>:  POST Content-Length of 25633071 bytes exceeds the limit of 20971520 bytes in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

`error_reporting` is set to 0...

```php
error_reporting(0);
```

But I'm still getting the error. How can I suppress this error so I can display my own error page?

The error messages are handled by exceptions

Comment: check the value of `ini_get('error_reporting')` to make sure it is actually set

Comment: turn error reporting off in php.ini rather than in the script.

Comment: `ini_get('error_reporting')` returns `32767`... I want to hide the error and instead throw my own errors

Comment: @WesleyMurch of course you can fix it. It's a setting controlled in php.ini... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size

Comment: @SetSailMedia It's very often not an option to edit php.ini, and even then it's not always a good idea to remove the limit. Your link merely speaks to increasing the limit. In order to never have this error occur you'd have to remove it entirely.

Comment: I think, this error appear before the script is executed, because the file is passed to the script by your web server. Can you try set error_reporting directly in your php.ini config file? Also check: post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, memory_limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ini_set('error_reporting')` doesn't work in this case because the error happens before the script is executed.

So you have to set it in php.ini.

But don't disable error reporting, errors can be very useful for you.

Hiding them from your users is enough (and recommended). You can do it by setting [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/fr/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to `0` in php.ini. Then enable [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/fr/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Using the tilde will stop errors of a certain type - This directive worked for me to stop showing warnings:

(line 514 of php.ini)
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE`