# Debian - Symfony 2 - The file "file" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 kb). (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, apache, symfony, file-upload, debian

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony 2 application on debian server.
The website works pretty well. However I meet this issue for the upload picture...

I try to upload a picture and my RestFul API returns this error :

```
The file "file.JPG" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 kb). (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I checked on internet how to resolve this problem. Apparently, I need to change the value of

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

I changed the value for 20M.
I've also changed the post_max_size. 
My new configuration is :

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

After updating, I did relaunch the server with this command :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

It doesn't change anything. I still have the same error :/ 
I'm root, so it's not a problem of permissions. With php info, I located the php.ini, so I guess that I change the right file.

I don't see any other solutions ...

Comment: Consider changing `post_max_size` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size

Comment: I tried this too ... 
I have `post_max_size = 20M` ... The problem is still here :/

Comment: Using PHP-FPM ? If yes - `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart`. Tried `apache2 restart` instead of `reload` ? Sure you're editing the right `php.ini` ? the php-CLI might have a different one -> `php -i | grep ini` can point to a different ini-file than `phpinfo();` !  Double-check `phpinfo()`'s path to the `php.ini` or just click on the PHP version in the symfony debug toolbar ..

Comment: No... I don't have Php-fpm. When I go inside init.d directory, there is not php-fpm... I tried /etc/init.d restart, and relaunch, the result is the same :/ ... When i'm editing php.ini, i'm sure to edit the right file. I edit the file with the path given by phpinfo() ... 
On the server, i did : php -i | grep "Configuration File" .

Comment: I meant that the path was given by the command php -i ... I haven't used phpinfo(). Now, I've just tried what you recommanded, I made a php file and I called the function phpinfo(), the path for the loaded configuration file is different than the path given by the command php -i ... Very weird. Thanks for your help. I've updated the right php.ini. Now it works very well !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @nifr, I followed his instruction and I tried to get the php info with a php file by calling the method `phpinfo()`. 
The path of `Loaded Configuration file` given by this call is different of the path given by the command `php -i | grep "Configuration File"`.

If you want to make some changes for php, be sure to change the right php.ini.
To be sure of the location of this file, just use the function `phpinfo()`. It's the best way

Comment: `php --ini` is actually the best way of knowing where your ini files are.