# Empty Post object in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

When try uploading a form with a file greater than 10mb in zf2, the post object will be empty. Meanwhile, I have checked the php INI file settings and the upload_max_filesize is 128M.
I really don't know where the error is coming from. I need help

Comment: You should post some code or better explain the context of your problem.

Comment: Answer below is probably the right one. If you just getting an empty post and this is a dev env then you could turn on error reporting heres the docs page http://uk1.php.net/function.error-reporting.php but like everything in PHP there is like a million different places you can define this. Don't forget to turn it off in production toooooooooo

Answer (score 2):

You may have to set `post_max_size` as well. See: [Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Also, use an inspector such as Firebug to make sure that the browser really is sending the POST data to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your, reply. I have set those variables in php.ini and yes the form is being submitted, but when the file size exceeds a certain calue , that is the post becomes empty

Comment: Add `phpinfo();` to one of the php pages on your server, and make sure that the values for `post_max_size` and `upload_filesize` reflect what you set them to. If not, maybe you're changing them in the wrong php.ini? If the values do show up correctly, then are you going through a proxy that might be throwing out your POST body?

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. Turns out that I was using the wrong ini file. Stack overflow, you guys are the best. Everything works fine. Once again thank you brian