# Update Post Max Size in Windows Server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed a plug in that the minimum requirement is 32M for post max size.

So I searched this in the web but I can't find the suggested files to be modified.

[Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

I can't find `php.ini` and `.htaccess` in the whole Wordpress folder.

Only Max upload size is configurable in wp-admin/network/settings.php

using `get_option( 'blog_upload_space' );`

How can I do this ?

I have looked at inetpub folder and can't find it there too.

inetpub:
AdminScripts
custerr
ftproot
history
logs
mailroot
temp
wwwroot

Comment: php.ini is not located in wordpress folder, its located in root directory of your server

Answer (score 0):

php.ini is not located in wordpress folder, its located in root directory of your server.
in XAMPP.

for, .htaccess its most of the times hidden, so search for hidden files, and if its not present you can create one. but beware, usually updating .htaccess files is not a good idea.

Comment: So i looked into inetpub, 
 AdminScripts
custerr
ftproot
history
logs
mailroot
temp
wwwroot
still cant find it here.

Comment: which package you are using? xampp or wampp?

Comment: We're using IIS for windows web server

Comment: then it would be located in Inetpub