# Php $_POST Data Limit

Tags: php, post

Php Post Data Limit

I am trying post a very long query string to my page, but halfway it got cut away,what should I set to resolve such issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The max size of the $_POST depends on php.ini file. It can be defined also with ini_set() or in .htaccess

The value to modify is post_max_size

See also [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

But if you need so much memory probably you have some problem in your application.