# How to limit overall file size?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I found a setting that set limit for a single file

```
validation: {
    sizeLimit: 51200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
}
```

How to implement validation as follows: any number can be uploaded to server but grand total must be less than 5mb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to make use of the [onValidate callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#validate).  There, you can keep a running total of all submitted file sizes.  Once you reach your max, you can start rejecting files.  For example:

```
var totalAllowedSize = 5000000,
    totalSizeSoFar = 0;

callbacks: {
    onValidate: function(data) {
        if (totalSizeSoFar + data.size > totalAllowedSize) {
            return false;
        }
        totalSizeSoFar += data.size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share with my final solution for 'fineuploader' with jquery wrapper.

```
 var totalAllowedSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
 var totalSizeSoFar = 0;
 var fuUrl = '[endpoint]';

$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: fuUrl
            }               
        }).on('complete', function (event, id, name, response) {
            __doPostBack('<%=btnUpdateClientAttachments.ClientID%>', null);
        }).on("validate", function (event, obj) {                
            var fSize = obj[0].size;               
            if (totalSizeSoFar + fSize > totalAllowedSize) {
                alert("Attachments attached to your email are over 10mb, please add link to your attachments instead");
                return false;
            }
            totalSizeSoFar += fSize;                
        });
```

PS Thanks again to Ray for idea

Comment: No need to use `.on` to contribute event handlers in your case.  Probably more efficient to use my example.

Comment: I'm still using in project fine uploader v.3 and did not get to code at 'onValidate' function. That's why rewrote it a bit

Answer (score -3):

I don't think fine uploader has that option (I don't use it). If you are using php, you can set the maximum POST size in your php.ini file. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Why use fin uploader when you can fairly easily create your own and control everything? Am I the only one who wants to control everything?

Comment: This is not really a helpful answer _at all_. The question was tagged `fine-uploader`, and you -- more or less -- provided your opinion as an answer. Also, I disagree that it is easy to create your own uploader (https://github.com/widen/fine-uploader/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed).

Comment: Fair point. I did however give a solution (hack) to the problem. I will refrain from giving my opinion as a solution in the future.

Comment: Also, your solution is not useful.  You are making the assumption that all files are sent in one request - not true.

Comment: Well sorry for trying to be helpful. Next time I see a question whose topic in which I am not an expert (all of them), I will just ignore it. Is that what you want?

Comment: Instead of providing incorrect advice? yes, please do

Comment: Maybe next time it won't be incorrect advice though.