# Unable to POST form with max_filesize

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Upload file is working fine with file size less than 2.9 MB but my phpinfo (localhost) showing **upload_max_filesize    64M**.

When trying to upload larger files, after form submit **$_POST** is empty and no file where uploaded.

here is my code:

```
        <?php
            function fileUpload($attachment){
                $target_file = UPLOADDIR.basename($attachment["name"]);
                if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                    return "Sorry, file already exists.";
                }
                if (move_uploaded_file($attachment["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    return "The file ". basename( $attachment["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    return $attachment;
                    return "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                fileUpload($_FILES['fileToUpload'])
            }
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Check the php execution time

Comment: You should also check post_max_size  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size

Comment: you mean max_execution_time its currently 120. i'm just looking for file upload size about 5 MB maximum.

Comment: @steven post_max_size is only 3M. is that an issue? do i need to increase it?

Comment: Yes it should be equal or greater than upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before uploading script you can set maximum upload size in your php code

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

or
You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After that run your code

and

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!

if you made any change or modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server(or localhost) to use new configuration.