# $_FILES is empty when upload in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, file, file-upload, upload

I was using the dropzone.js to handle the upload part in frontend, using JQuery.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

My testing case are:

Upload a 34 MB file. Works fine...
Upload a 27 MB file. Works fine...
Upload two files, each of them is 5 MB. Works fine...
Upload two files, 34 MB + 27 MB. *Fail* , `$_FILES` is an empty array

Here is the JQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            url: '<?= site_url("admin/video/upload"); ?>',
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 50,
            maxFilesize: 500, //500MB
            acceptedFiles: 'video/*',
            maxFiles: 100,
            init: function () {
                var myDropzone = this;

                myDropzone.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    $("#success, #fail").hide();
                    $("#" + response).show();
                });

                myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                    this.removeFile(file);
                });

                $("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
public function upload() {
    die(var_dump($_FILES));
}
```

So, why the `$_FILES` is empty and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The possible answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6135485/3648578](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6135485/3648578)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

34 MB + 27 MB = 61MB.

So you would be posting 61MB.

The default PHP values are 2 MB for upload_max_filesize, and 8 MB for post_max_size. Depending on your host, changing these two PHP variables can be done in a number of places with the most likely being php.ini or .htaccess (depending on your hosting situation)

Have you checked out these in your php.ini?

Maximum allowed size for each file uploaded.

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
```

Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize, this is the combined size of all uploaded files on each post event.

```
post_max_size = 40M
```

If you wanted to upload a max file size of 500mb than you could set both of the above value to 500mb. Remember that if you upload more than one file, the post_max_size needs to be the combined file size of the uploaded files for each post event. So if you uploaded two files of 500mb, you would set upload_max_filesize =501M and post_max_size = 1001M

Comment: but why can upload a file with 34mb and another 27mb but when try to upload two files with 34mb and 27mb the error comes? Which is the explanation?

Comment: I post the comment because I think that you need explain this to the OP in your answer ;-)