# Captiva Wordpress theme Error

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm using the Windows 7 operating system and have installed `WordPress` on my localhost. I'm using the `XAMPP` bundle.  I want to create a commerce site in WordPress. I chose the *captiva* theme for this. However, when I install the *Captiva* theme, it shows the following error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 36013235 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Are you sure you want to do this?

Please try again.
```

What is the mistake? How can I fix this issues?

Comment: The post_max_size in your php configuration is too small for the amount of data you are trying to transfer. Please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size for more information on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase one of the server's configuration option. You can control these using .htaccess, like so:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

If you do not use the `.htaccess` file, then you can alway set it in `php.ini` file by changing this line:

```
post_max_size = "50M"
```

Unfortunatelly it is not posible to change that value by `ini_set`

Comment: thanks sir error  fixed now showing another error sir like this      Captiva.Responsive.WordPress.WooCommerce.Theme.v1.4.1/ThemeInstall/captiva/admin‌​/redux-framework/ReduxCore/assets/css/vendor/jquery-ui-bootstrap/images