# PHP form post strange bug

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a basic html form. There are input file and input texts
I have a strange problem. When i post form(i completed all inputs), sometime server return all input. But sometime server return some input. Sorry about my english. 
My file

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <input name="money" type="text"  class="form-control money" placeholder="10.50">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="authorName"   type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Örn: Adam Fawer">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="imageFile" type="file">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="bookName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Örn: Olasılıksız">

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="pageNumber" type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="360">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="releaseDate" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="2015">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="publishedName"type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Arkadaş Yayınevi">
    </div>



<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="description" rows="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Kitap arka kapağını yazabilirsiniz."></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="book_description" rows="20" class="form-control" placeholder="İlanın hakkında bişeyler yazabilirsiniz."></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="qbutton blue create-book-save-button"><span style="margin-left:5px">KAYDET</span></button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
<?php
if($_POST)
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I complete form and submit. And i post same form with f5. But result is change.Sometimes like this

```
Array ( [money] => wqe [authorName] => w [bookName] => asd [pageNumber] => asda [releaseDate] => "asd [publishedName] => asd [description] => asd [book_description] => a )
```

or like this

```
Array ( [money] => asd [authorName] => sadas )
```

Demo : http://www.erkinakbudak.com/deneme.php
same problem in my localhost
I use VestaCp. apache, nginx(reverse proxy)

php.ini file
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11916554/ 
if my image file is very very small. There isn't problem.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the bug and it happens only when I choose a file. As long as I don't use the file control, everything works as it should.

Comment: Yep can confirm only if the file is big more then 100k

Comment: That probably means that the limit to the POST body is exceeded. I think this post has the answer you're looking for: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: @SeboZoltan yes my file is big more then 100k

Comment: @Osuwariboy i already check this link. My problem is not just input file.input file and other inputs. So there isn't file control

Comment: This should be a post body size issue indeed, try verifying if your ini file is the actual one by running phpinfo() or try forcing a post_max_size via [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata echo ini_get('post_max_size'); result is 20 M