# Image upload Laravel 5.3 using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5.3

I have a problem here. I am developing my web application and I want it to connect to my API through ajax. I am trying to send an image to my api through ajax from my form in the client side, which is the web.

So, here's my form in the client side..

```
{{ Form::open(['enctype' => "multipart/form-data", 'id' => 'addplant', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'col s12']) }}
  {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10%;">
      <div class="col s12  center">
        <img class="circle" id="image_url" src=""></a>
        {!! Form::file('image_url', array('id' => 'image', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        {{ Form::text('herbal_name', null, array('id' => 'herbal_name', 'class' => 'form-control validate')) }}
        {{ Form::label('herbal_name', 'Herbal Name') }}
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        {{ Form::text('scientific_name', null, array('id' => 'scientific_name', 'class' => 'form-control validate')) }}
        {{ Form::label('scientific_name', 'Scientific Name') }}
      </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::submit('Add plant', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary right add')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here's my ajax, still in the client side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".add").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/identificare_api/public/api/plants',
        data: new FormData($("#addplant")[0]),
        type: "POST",
        success: function( msg ) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('pangit');
        }
    });
 });
</script>
```

EDIT: and in my api, I just have this one

```
return json_encode($request->file('image_url'));
```

What am I missing here? Did I missed something?

**UPDATE:** I tried to apply the answer of @bfcior but when I try to `console.log(base64img)`, it will return this very long string and it's longer than you expected.

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNjYb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the issue but aren't you supposed to be using a button instead of a submit? I'd imagine using a submit is preventing the ajax from working because the form is being submitted to the server for processing.

EDIT: What happens when you click the submit button? Telling us will help stackoverflow users diagnose the problem.

Comment: still no go when changing the submit to button. Anyway, when I click the submit button, it returns null.

Comment: It could be that your ajax call can't access the url you've specified. Are you using XAMP or Homestead to test locally?

Comment: null came from the url I've specified. Yes, I'm using xampp and ran php artisan serve in my client side

Comment: What I would do is change the API to return a hardcoded message like "It works!" and then test. If you still receive a null response then you know the problem is your ajax call not being able to access the url. If it returns the message then the problem lies in your API.

Answer (score 0):

You handle the file by using:

```
$request->file('image_url');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#files

Comment: Check if there is something inside global var `dd($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to convert img into base64 and pass it as a param. Then in your controller/route you can decode the base64 and save to a file (if is needed).

```
{{ Form::open(['enctype' => "multipart/form-data", 'id' => 'addplant', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'col s12']) }}
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10%;">
      <div class="col s12  center">
        <img class="circle" id="image_url" src=""></a>
        {!! Form::file('image_url', array('id' => 'image', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        {{ Form::text('herbal_name', null, array('id' => 'herbal_name', 'class' => 'form-control validate')) }}
        {{ Form::label('herbal_name', 'Herbal Name') }}
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        {{ Form::text('scientific_name', null, array('id' => 'scientific_name', 'class' => 'form-control validate')) }}
        {{ Form::label('scientific_name', 'Scientific Name') }}
      </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::submit('Add plant', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary right add')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    });

    var base64img = null;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#image').change(function(){

            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader  = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                base64img = reader.result;
            }, false);


            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

        });

        $(".add").click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/identificare_api/public/api/plants',
                data: $("#addplant").serialize() + '&image_url=' + base64img,
                type: "POST",
                success: function( msg ) {
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('pangit');
                }
            });
         });
    });
</script>
```

and route

```
Route::post('identificare_api/public/api/plants', function (Request $request) {
    return json_encode($request->all());
});
```

Comment: Why does $_POST['image_url'] is too long?

Comment: Look at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: Please refer to my update above to see what does `base64img` returns.

Comment: What I mean is $_POST['image_url'] is very long when I tried decoding it using base64_decode($_POST['image_url'].  When I tried to return the decoded `$_POST['image_url']`, it returned false. According to (base64decode.net/php-base64-decode), base64_decode() will return false if the input contains character from outside the base64 alphabet.