# Where do I set the maximal POST length in PHP?

Tags: php, web

It seems like my PHP sent too many variables in POST mode to another PHP scripts, and the POST query got truncated in the middle. Therefore, some of the variables that I sent in the POST request were ignored. Where do I set the maximal length of that? Thanks.

Comment: Please, show some code. There are bunch of ways - sending some POST data - cUrl, file_put_contents, etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size