# php ajax file upload, $_FILE is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a blob object and some data need to be post to `fileHandler.php`

so I pack them into a FormData:

```
        console.log("start saving");
        var url1 = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var url2 = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataPack));
        console.log(url1);
        console.log(url2);
        fd.append('realName', dataPack.name);
        fd.append("ans", JSON.stringify(dataPack.ans));
        fd.append("log", JSON.stringify(dataPack.log));
        fd.append("part", dataPack.part);
        fd.append('fileToUpload', blob);
        window.postData = fd;
```

and upload them via ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../php/fileHandler.php',
        data: postData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function() {
            uploadSuccess();
        },
        error: function() {
            uploadFail();
        },
        progress: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            //make sure we can compute the length
            if(e.lengthComputable) {
                //calculate the percentage loaded
                var pct = parseInt((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

                //log percentage loaded
                $('#uploadProgress').width(pct+"%").text(pct+"%");
                console.log(pct);
            }
            //this usually happens when Content-Length isn't set
            else {
                console.warn('Content Length not reported!');
            }
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data ==="ok") {
            uploadSuccess();
        }
        else {
            uploadFail();
        }
    });
```

php file handler:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$realName = trim($_POST['realName']);
$part = $_POST['part'];
$ans = json_decode($_POST['ans']);
$log = json_decode($_POST['log']);
$fileNameNoEx = $target_dir . $realName . "-" . $part ."-". time();
$target_file = $fileNameNoEx . ".mp3";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //save files
        $f = fopen($fileNameNoEx.".txt", "w");
        fwrite($f, "Answer log:\n");
        foreach ($ans as $page => $val) {
            fwrite($f, "$page : $val\n");
        }
        fwrite($f, "\nPage switching event log:\n");
        foreach ($log as $l) {
            fwrite($f, "{$l->time}s  --->  {$l->page}\n");
        }
        fclose($f);
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        var_dump($ans);
        var_dump($log);
        var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($_FILES);
        var_dump($target_file);
        echo "asdsad";
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

then strange things happen, sometimes uploading failed, and I when I try to upload again(in console, with the same data), browser keep logging:

```
NULL
NULL
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
string(24) "uploads/--1500100885.mp3"
asdsadSorry, there was an error uploading your file.
```

it seems that `postData` is empty? But when I check the `postData` in browser console:

```
> postData.get("fileToUpload")
File {name: "blob", lastModified: 1500101804839, lastModifiedDate: Sat Jul 15 2017 14:56:44 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 12597888…}
> postData.get("realName")
"jjj"
```

why???? how can `$_FILES[]` and `$_POST[]` be emtpy?

This problem happens often when the file is very large.

Comment: you call `window.postData = fd;` then use `data: postData,`, are you sure you are accessing that correctly? Depending on where the code is, `postData` may not be the value you expect due to scope

Comment: @DelightedD0D I've checked window.postData in console, it surely exists.

Comment: sure, but you're not using `window.postData` you're using just `postData` in this line: `data: postData,`. what happens if you use `data: window.postData,`?

Comment: Not sure it maters in your code, depends on where the code is placed, yours might be fine

Comment: @DelightedD0D I've change the `postData` to `window.postData`, and test the ajax again in console, but the problem still exists.

Comment: gotcha fair enough

Comment: what do `uploadSuccess()` and `uploadFail()` do exactly, do either of them modify `window.postData`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D No, they are just dealing with UI.

Comment: How is `window.postData = fd;` related to the ajax call positionally? are they in the same function? Is there any code between setting the value and using it in the ajax call? If so, does any of that code modify `window.postData`?

Comment: Also, if you add `console.log(postData);` right before the ajax call, does it also report an empty object when the php side reports the failure?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I add `console.log(postData.get("fileToUpload"));` right before `console.log(data);` It do return a file object.

Comment: And you're saying that it works for most request but fails for some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a maximum post size, try to increase it:  [Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

If PHP didn't have this limit I could send an infinitely large POST to your web server until either it runs out of disk or RAM.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I only modified `upload_max_filesize` bug forget `post_max_size`! Thanks a lot!