# Angular post array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, post

I am trying to post a object array, I expect the post to post JSON like so

```
{"campaign":"ben",
"slots":[
      {                        
     "base_image": "base64 code here"
      }
       ]
}
```

When I post I get this in the console

> angular.js:9866 POST /ccuploader/Campaign/updateSlots 413 (Payload Too Large)
>   (anonymous) @ angular.js:9866
>   n @ angular.js:9667
>   f @ angular.js:9383
>   (anonymous) @ angular.js:13248
>   $eval @ angular.js:14466
>   $digest @ angular.js:14282
>   $apply @ angular.js:14571
>   (anonymous) @ angular.js:21571
>   dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
>   r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
>   app.js:71 failed

Im not sure why my post is not working. Can someone point out my mistake ?

**JavaScript code**

```
 $scope.SaveImage = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.somesite.co.uk/ccuploader/Campaign/updateSlots",
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param({ 'campaign': "name", 'slots': $scope.slots }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('success');
            console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    };
```

Comment: Why are you using ` $.param()`. And **post** means which post? electricity post? or letter post or $http post? :O

Comment: trying to do a  $http post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are sending a `base64` string on the `POST` request.
Most web servers have a **max** `POST` limit. 
You should configure your `server` to allow large `POST` params. 
Implementation is different from server to server.

If your server is using PHP refer this.
[Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Also it is better if you can upload images by `chunking` them. There are lot of libraries that does it. Otherwise your browser will hang and the request will eventually `timeout`. That's called the `multipart` upload.

You can upload **GBs** of images without no problem with `multipart` upload mechanism.

**UPDATE**

Also without using the `$.param` function just pass the parameters directly to the data object. Since the payload is heavy the `$.param` may throw this exception when it's trying to parse the request.

```
$scope.SaveImage = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.somesite.co.uk/ccuploader/Campaign/updateSlots",
            method: "POST",
            data: { 
                  campaign: "name",
                  slots: $scope.slots
            }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('success');
            console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into 'multipart', I am able to post from postman but unable to through my browser, would configuring my server to accept higher limit still be the problem ?

Comment: Nice, thanks, just ran it still getting 413 (Payload Too Large) but ill see about increasing the max size on the server