# download file from php do not properly work

Tags: php, download, plesk, chown

here is my code:

```
ob_start();
$mm_type="application/octet-stream";
$file = '../uploads/files/' . $filename;

header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($file)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

ob_end_clean();

readfile($file);
```

the script triggers the download but the file is not the right size.
My file must be 17Mo, but i download a 64Kb file each time.
I placed this line above my script:

```
$file = '../uploads/files/' . $filename;
echo "FileSize: " . filesize($file);
exit();
```

And it display 17566342, the right size.

This issue appear when i made a big mistake on plesk, i ran this command:

```
chown -R 10003:1003 /
```

All my system was down, i could repair it by update plesk and ran:

```
plesk repair fs
```

But since then, my download script doesn't work properly.

I checked rights, my uploads dir is 755, my files dir is set to 755 too, and the file is set on 644.

Comment: Check your php [post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer , i don't use POST method here, but i checked and my post_size is set to 32M

Comment: Oh, sorry misinterpreted your question *urg*. ```header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($file)) );``` doenst need to be a string. [Maybe your solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)