# 405 Method Not Allowed - Laravel axios post Base64 string image

Tags: javascript, image-processing, vue.js, base64, laravel-5.6

I am doing a project like Social media using Laravel and Vue. 
Here people can post up to 10 photos at a time.
But I want them resized before uploading using javascript. So that I converted them into base64 string image and then send them to Laravel intervention to make image and store them.

It works when I post 1/2 or 3 photos. But It shows "405 Method Not Allowed" when I upload more than 3 photos.

Where the problems exactly occurs ? Is  base64 string is too large for payload?

My route `Route::post('/user/post/submit', 'PostController@storePost');`

**My axios post method in Vue**

```
if (this.textInput != null || this.uploadedImages.length > 0) {

    axios.post("/user/post/submit", this.file).then(res => {
      //

    });
  }
```

**My Base64 string**

```
const vm = this;
  if (vm.uploadedImages.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.uploadedImages.length; i++) {
      let attachment = vm.uploadedImages[i][0];

      var base64_str = attachment.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
      var base64_str_rep = base64_str.replace(' ', '+');
          if(base64_str_rep){
            console.log(base64_str_rep)
            vm.file.append("images["+i+"]", base64_str_rep);
          }


    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but maybe this is caused by the size of the request. Did you try to use smaller images to see if it works. It should return 413 if the size is too large.

Comment: For 5 small size images it works. But not for medium size images. But I am compressing all the images to width 600px  using canvas.  My aim is to upload any size images but that will be  compress to 600px width images.

Comment: Then your problem is related to the maximum allowed size for a post request. Try to increase that limit. Look over this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check this also.