# Why can't import backup site WordPress? Plugin All-in-one migration

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I can't import in new localhost site my previous site which is on server? I am exported .wpress file and now I want to import. I using All-in-one plugin and toxedo plugin for maximum upload file size. Error which i got is

> "Unable to import Unable to open file for reading. File:
>   C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-wp-migration\storage\wdfoahbbl74z\myapp.com-20191120-060914-394.wpress"

When i go to see logs a see this:

> Nov 20 2019 12:38:59 {"type":2,"message":"POST Content-Length of
>   711871094 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040
>   bytes","file":"Unknown","line":0}
>
> Nov 20 2019 12:39:02 {"Number":2,"Message":"filesize(): stat failed
>   for
>   C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-wp-migration\storage\wdfoahbbl74z\myapp.com-20191120-060914-394.wpress","File":"C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-wp-migration\functions.php","Line":233}
>
> Nov 20 2019 12:39:02 {"Number":2,"Message":"Division by
>   zero","File":"C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-wp-migration\lib\model\import\class-ai1wm-import-validate.php","Line":67}
>
> Nov 20 2019 12:39:02
>   {"Number":2,"Message":"fopen(C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-wp-migration\storage\wdfoahbbl74z\myapp.com-20191120-060914-394.wpress):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory","File":"C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-wp-migration\lib\vendor\servmask\archiver\class-ai1wm-archiver.php","Line":98}

Did anyone know where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to

```
Nov 20 2019 12:38:59 {"type":2,"message":"POST Content-Length of 711871094 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 
bytes","file":"Unknown","line":0}
```

you need to change php settings to allow bigger POST size than 40M. the new value should be a bit bigger than your backup filesize

EDIT: during the chat we figured that bitnami has it's own php.ini in `C:/Bitnami/wordpres/php/php.ini` and this one had the bad (small) value. updating this file finally allowed to fix the issue with the POST limit.

Comment: I am new in WordPress. I using wordpres two days..Where I can change php settings? @janmyszkier

Comment: 1. this needs to be changed in php.ini of your web server. but see this post for more details:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size

Comment: I don't have php.ini. I working in localhost with Bitnami wordpress installation

Comment: you do, see: https://community.bitnami.com/t/where-is-php-ini/409

Comment: I find! I increasing all max time but again same error. Maybe i need restart apache server after changing php.ini file?? Where is problem ? @janmyszkier

Comment: Yes, please restart it and try again, if you get same errors, it might be that's not the correct php.ini, in that case run phpinfo in your local index.php and see what ini file your wordpress is using. I know wordpress may come with its own limit if it has beed not defined yet

Comment: Try to define define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' ); if error still tells you about 40m

Comment: Again error.
I know phpinfo() function but i am worked only with xampp...where is my index.php file?
Where to set ( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' ); ?

Comment: `index.php` is in your wordpress project root directory. please add `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' ); ` to that file next to other defines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202725/discussion-between-janmyszkier-and-aleksandarmihailovic).

Answer (score 0):

@flinty2000 solved it in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-open-file-for-reading-5/.

In my case, it worked just adding the extension (downloading the "basic" from https://import.wp-migration.com/ and uploading in my website through the plugin uploader).

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens in case when we use pulgin to increase the max import size or incase we haven't properly increased the the max import size in php service .

You can try below steps :

This might be weird solution but worked for me.

Step 1: find php.ini file in /etc folder  or / folder by running below cmd:

```
grep -rl "post_max_size" | xargs ls -lrth
```

Here I have used the post_max_size keyword to search the "php.ini" file in /etc folder ,but in some systems you can find this on /var/www/html or /var/www/wordpress folders.

We have multiple posts on the internet as if the php.ini file is not present in the WordPress folder then you can create but in my case that doesn't work.

Step 2:

Edit php.ini file and change the value like this.

```
post_max_size = 100M   
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

In the above you can set any value as per your requirement.

Step 3:

Restart the httpd or Nginx or apache and PHP service, or as per setup, you can restart the web service.

For me httpd and php-fpm service restart worked in centos 8 :

```
service httpd restart
service php-fpm restart
```