# Posting checkbox value via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, serialization, checkbox

Before marking it as duplicate ,please read my concern

I have a ajax which post checked checkbox serialized data.I have around 40k checkboxes selected .But when i dumping the serialized data count i am only getting around 20k count.Am i missing anything

```
var investors=investorDatatable.$("input[name='investors[]']:checked").serializeArray();
    console.log(investorDatatable.$("input[name='investors[]']:checked").length);
    console.log(investors);
    if(investors)
    {
    $('#loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: deleteMultipleUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  investors,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data['status'] = 'success') {
    }
```

first console ouput is `39862` 
second console ouput is an array of the 39862 records.

But when i dump the count in the controller it shows 20001

Comment: Try change data:  investors, ---> data:  {investors:investors}

Comment: Maybe your POST request exceed `post_max_size`?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: @AhmedRebai When i am doing like that the count becomes 10001

Comment: @Nazar Already post_max_size is 200M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send request as FormData and watch how many records transmited. You need to find where your data is cutted.

Comment: Actually i have situaution that is to send all the selcted checkboxes in the datatble.but i am sending it as formdata .it only posts the checkboxes which are on the DOM not the whole data .That;s why is use investorDatatable.$("input[name='investors[]']:checked").serializeArray()

Comment: Maybe try to add data to FormData manually. Also try to use POST-request (Postman, etc) utility to check if your server can accept so long json. `console.log(JSON.stringify(investors));` and then put it data to POST utility

Comment: when i use JSON.stringify(investors) on console it shows all the dat

Comment: Yep, and then make POST request with this data to url via Postman ([link](https://www.postman.com/))

Comment: thankyou for the answer when i used the JSON.stringify it works fine.