# Php song upload

Tags: php, upload

i'm trying to upload a song with an html form and a php code.
I've found on the net loads of scripts but noone seems to do the work.
I mean, it actually uploads little images but when it comes to upload big files (that can be even images and songs) it shows error 1.
Here it's the code i've used:

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="" />
<!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

OTHER FILE:

```
<?php


$uploaddir = '';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";


?>
```

the problem is that even if i change the value in name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="" /> i can't upload those "big" files.
I've already changed the value in the php.ini file to 20M

Comment: sounds like a server issue.  we need more info.  what is the output of the server log when you try to upload the song? can you post the source of move_uploaded_file?

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php

Comment: when i try yo upload a large file like a song it says
    Possible file upload attack!
    Array
    (
    [userfile] => Array
    (
    [name] => DSC_0929.jpg
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 1
    [size] => 0
    )

    )
move_uploaded_file is the basic php function

Answer (score 0):

**Error Messages Explained**

`Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: As i said i've already changed it but the result doesn't change

Comment: Did you restart the web server after you changed the value in php.ini?