# Maximum upload size for images

Tags: silverstripe

How can I assign to the upload field a maximum size of 4MB?
I tried this

```
$imageField = new SortableUploadField('Images', 'Images');
$imageField->setOverwriteWarning(FALSE);
$imageField->setAllowedMaxFileNumber(40);
$sizeMB = 4; // 4 MB
$size = $sizeMB * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB in bytes
$imageField->getValidator()->setAllowedMaxFileSize($size);
```

but I get an Internal server error / forbidden message.

Thank you

Comment: when do you get the error?

Comment: i get the error when trying to upload an image. The progress bar in the image is loadin in the CMS till 99% then stops and give me this error.

Comment: Same problem when i use new UploadField('Images', 'Images'); instead of SortableUploadField!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it works for me:

I found out that /framework/filesystem/GD.php
needs more than 64MB. Therefore i had to set php_value memory_limit 128M

Comment: glad you got it working, please accept this answer so that this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the max upload file size for the UploadField here.
the code seems correct.

however my guess is that you only set it here, but your server still only allows 2MB
see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263496/1119263 for how to change the upload size allowed by the webserver/php.

Comment: The server allows more than 2MB. I found out that after the upload of the "to big image" it is not possible anymore to go in the CMS menu "Files". By clicking on "Files" i get the same error message: Internal server error. Could it maybe be a problem that I do not resize the images when uploading them?

Answer (score -2):

```
$uploadField = new UploadField(
    $name = 'AttachedImages',
    $title = 'Attached Images'
);
$uploadField->getValidator()->setAllowedMaxFileSize( 4 * 1024 * 1024 );
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When progress bar finishes I get an Internal server error

Comment: it does work if all other parameters are correct. Which obviously was not the case in this question. Especially obvious because your code is already in the question.

Comment: Question is related to SilverStripe, not other parameters.
Especially obvious to check PHP settings before asking about CMS settings.

Comment: So if someone asks you why the .exe is not running then would tell him how to fix hit rather than asking if he is on a mac or linux before?

Comment: Yes. My fault is that I guess people are technically skilled to address direct question.

Comment: I thought that when I set a php_value memory_limit of 64M it should be enough for running silverstripe since in the documentation was recommended 48M. That's why I supposed there is something wrong in my code..