# Form submit doesn't work with a video

Tags: php, html, file, upload

so I spend quite a lot of time writing this script for uploading files and after I've done all the tests with some pictures I tried it with a small MP4 video I downloaded from Youtube (11mb) and it doesn't work. This is my form:

```
<form role="form" action="php/functions/uploadVideo.php" method="POST"
                      onsubmit="return checkFile(200097152)" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="videoTitle">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="videoTitle" placeholder="Enter a title..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="videoDescription" rows="5" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="videoTags">Tags</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="videoTags" placeholder="Separate tags with a commma..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                        <input type="file" name="videoFile" id="videoFile" required>
                    </div>
                    <center><button id="upload-video-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button></center>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">
                </form>
```

and this is my script:

```
$artistName  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$title       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['videoTitle']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['videoDescription']);
$tags        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['videoTags']);

$uploadsDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."bcm/videos/";
$tmpName     = $_FILES["videoFile"]["tmp_name"];
$name        = $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "$uploadsDir$name");
```

The result is undefined index on all the variables, as I said it works perfect with images but not with videos.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bcm/videos/"`

Comment: check all post values then use

Comment: there can be a server limit on the size of the files you post

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php for changing max-upload size of php.

Comment: Probably the file size as the above stated, but also check $_FILES["videoFile"]["error"] (and compare against : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: The size limit is checked by a JS function and it is set at 200mbs so that won't be the problem.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, the problem was in the php.ini file - I had to modify the upload max and post max variables.