# PHP Uploading Module restricts filesize > 2 KB

Tags: php, html, oracle, file, blob

I have my Upload File page written in HTML/PHP. The file's content gets stored in a `Blob` column of an Oracle table. The problem is that it only uploads file that is less than 2 KB and not the greator ones. The code below.

**Problem:**

Code only works for FileSize < 2 KB.

All these parameters are greator than 2KB.

- PHP: upload_max_filesize 2M
- PHP: post_max_size 8M
- PHP: max_input_time 60

**HTML:**

```
Please specify your file: 

<form  method="post" id = "myForm" name = "myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();">
<p style = "text-align:center"><img  align = 'middle' src = "logo.jpg" width="50%" height="100"></img></p>

<h3 align = 'center'><font color = 'orange'><u>Text File Upload</u></font></h3>
<div class = "center">
<select id = "selectPol" name = "selectPol"required >
<option value="">Please select file type</option>
<option value="choiceone">Choice One</option>
<option value="choicetwo">Choice Two</option>
</select>
</div>


<div class="center" id = "formDiv">

<br></br><input type="file" name="datafile" id = "datafile" />

<p>
<input type="submit" id = "save" name = "save" value="Upload"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</p>

<p style = "text-align:center" id="result"></p>
</div>
<div id = "f1_upload_process" name = "f1_upload_process" style = "text-align:center; display: none;">
<span style = "text-align:center"><font color = "orange"><b>Uploading. Please wait...</b></font></span><br>
<img  align = 'middle' src = "progress_bar.gif"></img>
</div>
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>                 
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) && $_FILES['datafile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['datafile']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['datafile']['size'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['datafile']['type'];
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp); 
$conn = OCILOGON("myDB","myDB","MYSERVER");
$qry = "INSERT INTO FilesTable (date_input,file_name,File_CONTENT) VALUES (SYSDATE,'$fileName',utl_raw.cast_to_raw('$content'))";


$stmt = OCIparse($conn,$qry);
ociexecute($stmt);

$result = oci_num_rows($stmt);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php

Comment: I don't have an experience with the `oci_*` lib however it certainly looks like you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection with your `$fileName` variable.

Comment: Can you put more of your form into your source?  For example does it include a MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field BEFORE the file input?

Comment: @GordonM There's no Hidden Field anywhere in the code..

Comment: @GordonM see edited question please.. You might get a good idea

Comment: There needs to be a MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden input in your form otherwise PHP will assume a very low default.  See the manual on file uploading.

Comment: @GordonM Can you share some link?

Comment: http://php.net/manual

Comment: @GordonM Thanks for your help! The problem was not with PHP but the query. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with PHP file size, the problem was with `utl_raw.cast_to_raw('$content')` in the query. It has a limitation when inserting more than 2KB in a Blob column.

Replaced my SQL code with:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO FilesTable (date_input,file_name,file_content) VALUES (SYSDATE,'$fileName',empty_blob()) RETURNING file_content INTO :file_content";
$stmt = OCIparse($conn,$qry);
$blob = ocinewdescriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
ocibindbyname($stmt, ":file_content", $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
ociexecute($stmt);
ocicommit($conn);
ocifreestatement($stmt);
```

And it works :)