# Can't upload theme on website, need to increase PHP

Tags: php, themes, uploading

I cannot upload 2 themes to my Wordpress website and the help message suggest to increase my PHP settings.  Here is the exact request to fix the problem.

Then the PHP version should set to 7.0 or higher and your PHP limits need to be increased, specifically are:

```
upload_max-Size = 64m
post_maxsize = 96m
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload max size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php)

Comment: Frank, in your question, did you accidentally omit thhe "exact request to fix the problem"? Or are the are the next two lines the request, but you didn't quote them? TIA.