# Upload large files to FTP with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload large files with php to an ftp server.  I can upload small files, but I'm having trouble uploading larger files.  I have looked it up and found that I need to set upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, set ftp to passive mode, and set time limit to never.  I had no luck with setting the time limit, and what I have now isn't returning any errors, but it is also not uploading the file.  If you look at the `if (!$upload) {` line at the bottom, it should echo something, but it isn't.  More importantly, it just isn't working.  Any insight as to what is going wrong or what I need to do to make this work?  Thank you!

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');   
ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');  

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name";
        exit;
}

 // turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

if($_FILES['upload_file']['name']!=''){
    $source_file = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];
    $destination_file = $_FILES['upload_file']['name']; 

    // upload the file
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);

    // check upload status
    if (!$upload) {
            echo "FTP upload has failed!<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file<br />";
        }       
}
```

### UPDATE

I've discovered that I cannot set the upload_max_filesize value from the php page; also, I can't seem to get .htaccess to work: if I have an .htaccess file it results in a HTTP Error 500.  Also, I don't have access to php.ini.

How else can I change the upload_max_filesize value?

### More Information

My web administrator has told me that I am on an IIS windows-based system, so .htaccess files won't work.  Is there a way that I can affect the file upload size with web.config?

Comment: Where did you set the timelimit?

Comment: some hosting companies will only let you set that so high.  Also, rather than setting it everytime the script runs, why not just put it in the php.ini file?

Comment: Is the page loading for ever? If not, the reason that it doesn't echo something must be because `$_FILES['upload_file']['name']` is `''`. And make sure error reporting is on.

Comment: @fhugas I set it at the very top: set_time_limit(0)

Comment: @Sietse How do I turn error reporting on?  It will upload small files, but not large files.

Comment: You can turn it on with `error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: You sure set_time_limit() is working? Some hosts require you to make a php.ini file in the directory where your php file resides.

Comment: @Sietse Error reporting didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: for the web config, maybe you can have a look at the http runtime section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.php

> 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size'

are of type PHP_INI_PERDIR

which means Entry can be set in "php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf". So you can't set it in your script.

--- Edit ---

A similar question:
[Changing upload_max_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

--- Edit 2 ---

Personally, I wanted to do the same kind of stuff (upload large files over ftp) and end up writing a java application. For handling large files, php is not really the best way. Web browsers doesn't really like that. So, for handling large files, I would suggest to look at other alternative: (java, swf, javascript, ...)

Something I would like to give a try when I have some time is http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Comment: @AngeDeLaMort Wow.  I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: never knew about this. removed -1, +1 for correctly pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

as rightly pointed out by @AngeDeLaMort, you cannot use shorthand notation to set configuration values outside of PHP.ini.

reference : [Changing upload_max_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

try doing it this way.

create .htaccess file in your root directory and add the following.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: Page cannot be displayed when I create an .htaccess file: HTTP Error 500

Comment: do you have any other rule set up in your .htaccess file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10748/discussion-between-bozdoz-and-ibrahim-azhar-armar)

Comment: please make sure you place .htaccess file in the correct directory.

Comment: I put it in the same directory as the php page.  It results in an HTTP Error 500

Comment: place the file in the root directory, i.e if you are using linux server then directly in `public_html` directory or in windows `www` directory.