# How to upload multiple files of local folder to ftp folder?

Tags: php, ftp

Error in uploading files of local folder to ftp folder

I tried with ftp_put method and it is not working for large files

```
function UploadMasterFiles() //uploading files from local folder to ftp
{
    try
    {
       $connection = ftp_connect($ip, $port, $timeout);
       $login_result = ftp_login($connection, $un, $pw);

      $dir = getcwd()."\\files";

      // Open a directory, and read its contents
      if($connection)
      {    
        if (is_dir($dir))
        {
          if ($dh = opendir($dir))
          {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {

              if($file !== "." && $file !== "..")
              {

               if (ftp_put($connection,"FOLD\\SPLITFILES\\".$file,$dir."\\".$file,FTP_ASCII))
                {
                  //echo success;
                }
              }
              else{}
            }
           closedir($dh);
          }
       }
      }
      else
      {
        //echo "not connected";
      }
  }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
      echo "\n Exception Caught", $e->getMessage(); 
   }
}
```

I have files in my local folder named "files" and want to transfer to my ftp server folder "SPLITFILES". This is the task I want to do.

Now, I am getting error at "if (ftp_put($connection,"FOLD\files\".$file,$dir."\".$file,FTP_ASCII))" this line. warning message is "ftp_put Transfer complete". but files not get transferred. But if files are of less size then this is working. I am unable to pick where the problem is. Please guide me where I am wrong.

Comment: May be it's related to the max allowed size of files? Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399413/2660253

Comment: my files size ranges from 1kb- 300kb max.

Answer (score 0):

use this

**ftp_put($connection, "FOLD\SPLITFILES\".$file, $dir."\".$file, FTP_BINARY)**

Reply if error still exists.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - what have you changed, and why?

Comment: The "FTP_BINARY" transfer mode of FTP copies files exactly, byte for byte. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: Please add all such information to the answer itself, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain why that helps to transfer large files