# cakephp ini_set not working

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, upload, cakephp-2.1, ini-set

I want to upload big file in my admin panel but not in every where and public users access to upload big file ,
I use ini_set in my core.php , bootstrap , controller , ... but its not working for me ,
My ini_set is :

```
ini_set("memory_limit","300M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','200M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '200');
ini_set('max_input_time','200');
```

Thanks

Comment: whats the output of `var_dump(ini_set(...));`

Comment: its return false for some one :
128M ,
false , 
false , 
30 , 
false ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with CakePHP. Values like "upload_max_filesize" cannot be changed using ini_set(). Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php#1122443).

Comment: are you say i cannot change "upload_max_filesize" on the fly and only put it in .htaccess or php.ini ?

Comment: my problem is i dont want access public user to upload big file .

Comment: Yes you cannot change that value from php script itself. So set it to whatever max. value you want from php.ini or .htaccess and then add validations in your application to prevent public users from uploading  large files. In HTML5 you can add client side validation too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you/cakephp setting the ini values inside of a .htaccess file as well? Could be some sort of overriding happening.

Comment: i can put & use ini in my .htaccess and its working but i do not want public user access uploading big file .