# Can't get php.ini's updated value

Tags: php

I have changed php.ini's some value in `php.ini` file and also through php script like,

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('POST_MAX_SIZE', '10MB');
```

but when I am running `phpinfo()` it doesn't shows the updated value.

It shows

`upload_max_filesize = 2M`

I am wondering how it is possible??

Comment: Check to see which php.ini file is being loaded. It's likely not the one you think.

Comment: Did you restart your apache?

Comment: check if `phpinfo()` shows the path to your `php.ini`

Comment: i have already restarted apache

Comment: probably wrong php.ini. Do you use something as WAMP, XAMP etc? Or have you installed PHP, Apache etc. manually?

Comment: you are most likely editting the wrong php.ini. when you have a local installed server (not wamp, xampp, lamp etc) edit the php.ini in your apache folder.

Comment: there are two different paths to php.ini                   Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File         D:\xampp\php\php.ini which one should i update?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld  i am using xampp server.

Comment: I guess it would be the D:\xampp\php\php.ini since you are using xampp. Try edit that one, and restart again. I don't know how Xampp works, but WAMP has menu in the taskbar where you can edit php.ini. If Xampp has anything similar use that, then u will be assured you're editing the correct file.

Comment: there are two php.ini files.1.php.ini-production 2.php.ini-development  I have edited both of these..but there is no effect.

Comment: There should be a file just called php.ini. (not production or development). Can you find that?

Comment: You cannot change these values using ini_set.

Comment: yes.there is another php.ini file.which was loadedby apache.Solved.Thanx for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, and as Salman mentiod these values cannot be changed through your php-script.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to your Apache configuration ?

Maybe theses parameters are overridden in the virtual host of the Apache configuration via php_admin_value. If this is the case, then you won't be able to change this value in the php script itself.

Also, check the following post : [Changing upload_max_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is very common for your environment to contain several `php.ini` files, where the one you're editing is not actually being used. Check `php_info()` output for the path to the loaded configuration file to double check.

If it's definitely correct, restart your web server and double-check it's still not loading.

If you still got no luck, have a look at the return values for `ini_set()`:

```
if(ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M') === FALSE ||
   ini_set('POST_MAX_SIZE', '10MB') === FALSE)
{
    echo "Failed to set a configuration parameter.";
} else {
    // These functions returned strings containing the old value.
}
```

Let us know what the above returns for you.