# Increase file upload size but cannot locate/access php.ini

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm testing a file uploading page etc that I'm working on.  Chose a largish file at random and received:

Request Entity Too Large

```
The requested resource
/admin.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

as an error message.  Brief google led to changing values in php.ini but I can't locate or access it.

The site is hosted on a free site 000.webhosting.org - I'm guessing they have it restricted somehow.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can't get access to php.ini on a free host. Even many paid hosts don't allow you to access that.

Comment: @Fallen - OK.  ANy way around the max upload size then?

Comment: I believe there's no way to increase `upload_max_filesize` from php code. For further reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Comment: unfortunately, no workaround for this issue. It is a protection mechanism set by this type of hosts to protect themselves from massive/multiple uploads that could affect both bandwith and lock a server thread too long.

Comment: @Paul - OK.  To be honest it's only a server that I'm using for testing and so on, the site will be migrated to a paid service where hopefully settings will be more pliable

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess document and put it in you document root directory. Inside, place:

`php_value upload_max_filesize 10M`

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Honestly, I've never tried this, but it appears to be what you need.

Edit:

Here's something else I found, you can try: `ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "xM");` where x is a number and the M signifies Megabytes. I'm not sure if it works with all versions, but it's listed as being editable on the php website (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Comment: Making any changes to the htaccess except errorDocument for 404 prevents page / site from displaying.  Crafty free web host. :)

Comment: The edit above should work, but you'll need it on every page that needs the increased upload size.