# PHP not uploading file over 55 kb

Tags: php, file, upload

Files more than 50 KB are not uploading. I have checked php.ini and i have following values

```
post_max_size = 16M (which i have increased from 3 MB but still no luck)
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

I've tried and read everything, couldn't find a solution, if anyone has gone thru the same problem, please share your experience.

## PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0)
    {
        $uploaded_file_name =  $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . "/" . $uploaded_file_name);
        exit;
    }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you restarted apache since making the change?

Comment: @Mooseman `ini_set` cannot change upload limits as they are used before the page is processed. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1122443/1392533)

Comment: If you have restarted apache, post your upload code. It could be setting its own maximum.

Comment: From Docs: http://php.net/manual/de/function.ini-set.php Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

Comment: i restart whenever i change anything

i have updated the question with code

Answer (score 1):

The post_max_size must be equal or greater than upload_file_size

**Example**

```
 ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
 upload_max_filesize = 64M

 ; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize  
 post_max_size = 64M
```

Comment: Yes 55kk is less than 16M maybe you need to restart apache2

Comment: i have updated post_max_size from 16 to 64M and have verified with phpinfo(), still no difference

Comment: Did you restart your apache after updating it ?