# PHP file uploading doesn't work over 65KB

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, apache

I have a VB.NET software that uploads files using an HTTP request to PHP. This worked fine until May but now it fails when uploading files over 65KB. I can not tell when it stops to work exactly. Even though, I don't think it is relevant. So to be clear, uploading a file under 65KB works correctly.

I looked with my hoster and he doesn't see any error neither do I on the server (the part I have access). VB.NET doesn't give me a pertinent error, but using WireShark, I've been able to get either a 500 or a 400 error. But it didn't give me clues on what is failing.

I verified this question which is not solved, though the things said there are OK on the server too.
[PHP not uploading file over 55 kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839741/php-not-uploading-file-over-55-kb)

I have another option to fix it: splitting my files in chunks of 50KB and rejoining them via PHP. Though, I rather understand what is happening because this can happen again even with chunks of 50KB.

Server is Apache/2.4.28 (Unix)

**EDIT 1**
I have new conditions: I now have my own server running on Windows + Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.6.

Now it goes a little farther. I have an error when using move_uploaded_file function that gives me: Error #3: The uploaded file was only partially uploaded. It is coherent with the file being stopped to be sent near the end. So I now receive an HTTP 200 response but a failure after ward even though I suspect not being there.

- I can certify I did not stop my VB.NET software that is uploading the file.
- I tested changing KeepAlive to Off/False on both sides. No luck :(
- Tried to add `header ("Connection: close");` in my main file (that is used for all transactions with this VB.NET software). No luck.
- Even though, it is not currently an issue, I changed (PHP configs) the upload_max_filesize to 256M and post_max_size to 300M (because it will be a problem if a can figure out this one).

I got those suggestions from : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176465/failed-media-upload-the-uploaded-file-was-only-partially-uploaded

The only one I could not try is replacing an apache/php module which doesn't seem to exist on Windows.

Comment: Do you have any middleware sitting in between your uploader and your server - a proxy perhaps or any other tool?

Comment: Nope, but good question. Well... let me check if I let a proxy on. I don't think so. OK, confirmed. I have not.

Comment: @raina77ow I forgot to put your name in. So my answer is just above.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server's configuration, when an error 500 is returned an `error_log` is written. The problem is with the error 400. Which according to [wikipedia's list of HTTP codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) is actually a **BAD REQUEST**. Some output from your error_log when the attempt is being made might put us in the right direction.

Comment: I would like, but neither the person who is hosting or me are seeing any error log.

Comment: If you're posting to a PHP file, you can make sure that you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the TOP of your php file (right after <?); This will generate a file called `error_log` in your file's path.

Comment: OK! This was an old PHP code, so I refreshed it to my latest framework version and I added `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Unfortunately, no error in error_log. But that is maybe normal because it is an error 400. Do you have any clues to give to my host so we could figure out what is happening?

Comment: Maybe you could check your apache's error_log ? Could be a faulty module or something too. It's really hard to pinpoint the issue. If it's NOT a PHP error then it's more likely an apache/apache module error.

Comment: Can you look at my **EDIT 1** please? Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it! It was on VB.NET side and I really don't understand what is happening. I was setting the ContentLength header and without it, BANG, it works. Thank you anyway. Shall I accept your answer anyway or create mine?