# read big text file (24mb) using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        // Create Reader.
        var xmlFile = document.getElementById( 'xmlFile' ).files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText( xmlFile );
        reader.onload = function( event )
        {
            var XMLData = event.target.result;
            alert(XMLData);

            jQuery.ajax
            ({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: "POST",
                data:   {
                            action: 'upload_products',
                            XMLData: XMLData
                },
                success: function( data )
                {
                },
                error: function( data )
                {
                }
            });
        };
```

**sample text file: it contains large number of products in it.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <TABLE-RECORDS>
      <EXPORT-RECORDS>
        <!-- product 1 -->
        <PRODUCT>
          <PRODUCTS_NAME>Panasonic Super Heavy Duty Battery AA - 4 Pack</PRODUCTS_NAME>
          <PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>fully functional whenever you need them.</PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>
          <PRODUCTS_IMAGE>1019.jpg</PRODUCTS_IMAGE>
          <PRODUCTS_PRICE>1.90</PRODUCTS_PRICE>
          <PRODUCTS_MODEL>1019</PRODUCTS_MODEL>
          <ITEM_BRANDNAME>Panasonic</ITEM_BRANDNAME>
          <ITEM_UPC>073096500235</ITEM_UPC>
          <ITEM_HEIGHT>0.500</ITEM_HEIGHT>
          <ITEM_LENGTH>4.250</ITEM_LENGTH>
          <ITEM_DIAMETER>3.375</ITEM_DIAMETER>
          <PRODUCTS_WEIGHT>0.16</PRODUCTS_WEIGHT>
          <MANUFACTURERS_NAME>Utm distributing</MANUFACTURERS_NAME>
          <ITEM_VENDOR_NUMBER>UM-3NPA/4B</ITEM_VENDOR_NUMBER>
          <DATE_RECIEVED>0000-00-00 00:00:00</DATE_RECIEVED>
          <PROP_PACKAGING>Blister Card</PROP_PACKAGING>
          <PRODUCT_CLASS>BAT</PRODUCT_CLASS>
          <PRODUCTS_TYPE>Batteries</PRODUCTS_TYPE>
        </PRODUCT>
        <!-- product 2 and so on -->
        <PRODUCT>
        ....
       </PRODUCT>
      </TABLE-RECORDS>
   </EXPORT-RECORDS>
```

This is my code. The above code is working nicely for small files but for larger files it crashes. how can i read large files? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "it crashes?" - are you getting a timeout error? some other error?

Comment: its going into the ajax error function. plus i alert the `alert(XMLData);` and it is only reading file to 173 rows and no more.

Comment: @HassanAli so the problem is not in _read big text file_ but in _sending big file via POST_?

Comment: yes maybe that will solve my issue. how do i read all the content?

Comment: @HassanAli - perhaps this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php (default max upload size in php is 2Mb)

Comment: i have put 200M already in my php.ini. @jogesh_pi where i put this code `set_time_limit(0);`?

Comment: @HassanAli `ajaxurl` is this hold a PHP file? if yes the then set in the very top of it.

Comment: yes it is. okay i will set it and check

Comment: i found the issue. its because my file is not getting read 100% thats why i am getting these issues. i do i read my file and save its chunks in a array? any idea?