# Why can't I get $_FILES[“file”][“tmp_name”] when uploading a zip file？

Tags: javascript, php

It's my first time here and I wonder if you could understand my question for I am not from an English-speaking country.

I want to write some code to upload a file, my code is quite easy to understand if you are know PHP or JS. Here is my code.

```
<form action='data.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='file' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>

$user_uid = rand(0, 50000);
$file_pos = strpos($_FILES['file']['type'], '/');
$file_name = $user_uid . '.' . substr($_FILES['file']['type'], $file_pos + 1);
$savePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\' . $file_name;
copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $savePath);
```

As above, I want to get the `tmp_name` of a file, but it does not work if a zip file or 7z file is uploaded. But it seems to work quite well for jpg or others, why?

I tried to output the $_FILES['file'] of a 7z, example below:

> Object {name: "2.zip", type: "", tmp_name: "", error: 1, size: 0}

I find the tmp_name is "" so does its type if 7z, how does that happen? And if I want to upload a zip or 7z, how should I change my code?

---

@2017.09.13

increase that in php.ini and restart the server

```
upload_max_filesize = 180M
max_file_uploads = 180
upload_max_filesize = 180M
```

Comment: what is the size of the image that you are uploading did you try with very small sized zip images?

Comment: If the file is more than 1MB, with a default configuration, the file would be too big.

Comment: It's not because it's a ZIP. You'll have to look up the error code you're getting there (`error: 1`). Probably size-related.

Comment: Please read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase that in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 180M
max_file_uploads = 180
upload_max_filesize = 180M
```

Comment: i try to change, but it still not work. the page says "Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\ajax\data.php on line 25" and the line 25 is "copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $savePath);" it seem that if i upload a zip i cannot get the $_FILES['file']['type'] as i want. but thanks all the same!

Comment: What is the output of `$_FILES['file']`?

Comment: Object {name: "2.zip", type: "", tmp_name: "", error: 1, size: 0} as above

Comment: but if a upload a small zip file, i can do that, but i really change the setting, i don't know why

Comment: Check the above configuration made or not using ini_get function.

Comment: It won't be because it's a ZIP.

Comment: its better to write `upload_max_filesize` four times in **php.ini** , then restart the webserver

Answer (score 1):

Reading http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php shows `error = 1` to be

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>   Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

So increasing the `upload_max_filesize` limit would solve your issue (this will help [Changing upload_max_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php))

Answer (score 0):

Try this mothod:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
$allowed =  array('rar','zip' ,'7z', 'RAR', 'ZIP', '7Z');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
echo '0';
} else {
// If no errors, upload the file
$target = "../fisiere_pub/"; //choose your upload folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$file = $target . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 }
} else $file = "Upload error!";
echo $file;
```

If this code is not working, try with small files (up to 5mb) or change the maximum filesize for upload in php.ini as other users mentions :)

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$NewPath.$FileName);
```

This works perfectly !

Look at : [PHP File upload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-354)

Comment: He probably has this as he can upload an image

Comment: i may not catch the string of $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']