# Change "upload_max_filesize" in Google Compute Engine more that 2M gives 500 server error

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

I'm using Google Compute Engine with a lamp instance.

I located my `php.ini` file here `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
and I edited with `sudo nano php.ini`.

Whatever variable I gave except the default one which is `2M` to `upload_max_filesize` it give me a 500 server error when I try to upload an image.

Of course I restarted my server after my modifications.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You tagged this question with "google-compute-engine" (rather than "php"). What makes you believe that it is specific to GCE?

Comment: Hi @AndreasVeithen, sorry for my late response. Yes I think that is 'google-compute-engine' related and not just PHP because on my local mamp server working fine with more than 2Mb. Only on 'google-compute-engine' looks like it doesn't let you to edit the `upload_max_filesize `.

Comment: Check out this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing upload\_max\_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)