# .JPEG .JPG High Quality images not uploading in PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I am making a website using profile picture uploader in the beginning i thought it was working great but yesterday i photographed some photos with my Camera which is a Sony DSC-h400 and it has 20MegaPixels in image quality after that i tried to upload it to my localhost website using PHP uploading script,well it didn't work and then i tried with the [w3schools.com PHP Upload Script](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) but it always give me this error :

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\tests\upload_img_w3c\upload.php on line 8
>
> File is not an image.Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are
>   allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

**NOTE** : I tried with the low quality .jpeg .jpg images (133Ko) But not working either,and i searched in google for an error similar to this but it looks like I'm the only one.

**NOTE 2** : The high quality image size was 6.44 MB.

I would appreciate any help even if it's not working.

Comment: please post your exact code

Comment: @DanieleD Here is the code http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp From the official w3schools Website

Comment: try increasing the `upload` file size in php ini

Comment: Yeah thanks very much http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,36154,36155 And now it's working great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the `upload_max_filesize`? It needs to be changed to allow bigger file uploads.

See this thread: [Changing upload_max_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i made some researchs and found this http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,36154,36155 And now it's working great

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")) 
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))     // set yourimg size ..
  { 
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
    { 
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />"; 
    } 
  else 
    { 


    if (file_exists("upload/temple/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
      { 

      } 
    else 
      { 
              chmod("upload/temple/",0777); 
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
      "upload//temple/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
      //copy("upload/".$FILES["file"]["name"]); 
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/temple/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
      } 
    } 
  } 
else 
  { 
  echo "Invalid file"; 
  } 

?>
```

Comment: Changed max size but not working,low quality images are getting uploaded normally but the others (6MB and higher) aren't

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.