# Import data not process 100% in magneto

Tags: php, magento

When I import the data of 45065 records it processed 42 data and stop further.
I have done all setting like.
`post_max_size (currently is 1024M) and upload_max_filesize (currently is 1024M) 
max_input_time = 60`.

Here I attached the screen shots, please assist me on how to fix this issue so that the data is processed 100%.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess  It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error are telling you is you need to up those PHP settings, so post_max_size needs to be bigger than 1024M and so on. try 3072M? I would also change maxi_input_time to something higher. But there isn't one setting that can fix this for you, it's more trial and error - as a side note it's not usually recommended to use Magento's default import/export as it's so buggy (slow, fails, etc.) Magmi is a much better solution.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: Thanks magmi fixed my issue.