# Wordpress max_upload_filesize not changing. Why?

Tags: wordpress

I have literally tried everything to change the `max_upload_filesize`:

1) changing in php theme function file

2) adding `php.ini` and `php5.ini` to the website root and also to the wp-admin folder

3) adding to `.htaccess` file

4) adding to `wp-config` file

But nothing works. I have called `phpinfo()` in the index.php file to check the values and it says 2M.

**Edit:** My server configuration has set the max_upload_filesize to 32M but my site's is 2M.

Comment: Seems like you should change it in .htaccess:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Comment: which cpanel you are currently using? First of all you need check you Cpanel setting for max_upload_filesize

Comment: I am using GoDaddy. Cpanel setting for max_upload_filesize set by server is 32M.

Answer (score 0):

Try one more way.

Use your ftp program and navigate to your WordPress root directory.

Find your wp-config.php and download a copy to your computer as backup.

Open up wp-config.php using your plain text editor or code editor.

Insert the following code at the end of the file.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

Comment: Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this plugin to increase max_upload_filesize

Increase Max Upload Filesize

https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/