# uploading of file is showing error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a webApp in which I am trying to let user upload image.
My code in `codeigniter` is :

```
 $config['upload_path'] =  './uploads/';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
 $config['max_size']     = '0';
 $config['overwrite']  = TRUE;
 $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
 $config['detect_mime'] = TRUE;
 $config['mod_mime_fix'] = TRUE;  
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

But it is showing error:

> The uploaded file exceeds the maximum size allowed by the submission form.

But when I try to upload same file without using PHP in other webapp it is uploaded.

Comment: So, change php.ini settings.

Comment: you need to change the value of **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** in php.ini file.after that restart apache server.

Comment: Refere this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Answer (score -1):

You have to change $config['max_size'] = '0';  to any other size like $config['max_size']     = '100';