# Upload the file of size more than upload_max_filesize in php

Tags: php, file, configuration

My requirement is that,I wanna upload the files of size more than `upload_max_filesize` in `php` without changing the `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`.
Without changing the `upload_max_filesize`, input `filefield` is not accepting the files by showing error.
Is there any chance to achieve this? Please suggest me to sort out this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure but i think this answer is helpful to you.[https://stackoverflow.com/a/27911708/4781696]

Comment: [File upload using chunk](https://www.codewife.com/php-large-file-upload-in-chunks/) This will might be helpful for you.

Comment: yeah it is fine but  could not able to download the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can upload the file of size more than `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`.
create a file `.htaccess` and paste the following code 
`php_value upload_max_filesize 10M` and save it in your project folder,that's it works fine.

Comment: this `.htaccess` will effect only the containing folder and its all sub folders