# some keys in $_FILES are empty

Tags: php, html

So I'm working on a website for my mom where she wants to upload photo's from her camera, I first tested my code with a normal picture that I found on my computer that was created in photoshop CS6 and the $_FILES array was okay:

```
array ( 'img' => array ( 'name' => array ( 0 => 'pic01.jpg', ), 'type' => array ( 0 => 'image/jpeg', ), 'tmp_name' => array ( 0 => 'D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpF0F7.tmp', ), 'error' => array ( 0 => 0, ), 'size' => array ( 0 => 6311, ), ), )
```

but when I try to upload a photo of my phone and hers I get the following array:

```
array ( 'img' => array ( 'name' => array ( 0 => 'IMG_20180228_143837.jpg', ), 'type' => array ( 0 => '', ), 'tmp_name' => array ( 0 => '', ), 'error' => array ( 0 => 1, ), 'size' => array ( 0 => 0, ), ), )
```

as you can see the type, tmp_name and size are empty or incorrect(the size is incorrect). I also see that the error array value is changed from 0 to 1.

both of these array exports are made by `var_export($_FILES);`

I use the following HTML code to upload the image:

```
<form method="post" action="updateproduct.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">{
      <input name="img[]" id="fileupload" type="file" multiple />
```

I hope I have given enough information if not please say so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PHP accepts file uploads just [under 2MB](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads). Consider changing it to something more realistic (like 200MB) in your PHP config (`php.ini`). Also do not forget to increase another relevant option [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), which should be somewhat larger than [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize).

Btw, here's a nice [helper function](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#89374) that will translate encoded error to the human readable message:

```
    function codeToMessage($code) 
    { 
        switch ($code) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form";
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 
                $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: 
                $message = "No file was uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
                $message = "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
                $message = "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
                $message = "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                break; 

            default: 
                $message = "Unknown upload error"; 
                break; 
        } 
        return $message; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An error value of 1 in your `$_FILES` array means you've exceeded the file size limit imposed by the server:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in php.ini.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)